# Precedence rules for matching groups with regexp

Tags: .net, regex, operator-precedence, capturing-group

Consider the following .NET regular expression:

```
^(REF)?(.{1,10})-(\d{12})-(\d+)$
```

It defines four groups, in which I'm interested and which I will analyse separately.

Now, consider an input string for this regexp:

```
REFmisc03-123456789012-213
```

It is possible to match it like this:

```
(REF)(misc03)-(123456789012)-(213)
```

And it is also possible to match it like this:

```
()(REFmisc03)-(123456789012)-(213)
```

**Is it documented what way will be preferred by the regexp engine, or is it random?**

Comment: I don't know the answer off hand, but I would bet against randomness being a factor.  Build yourself a quick test case and see what results you get.  Different regex engines might parse it differently, but I would expect consistent results from any given engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not random. This boils down to how quantifiers are interpreted by the regex engine and potential backtracking. By quantifier I am referring to the `?` in `(REF)?`. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx):

> Ordinarily, quantifiers are greedy; they cause the regular expression
>   engine to match as many occurrences of particular patterns as
>   possible. Appending the ? character to a quantifier makes it lazy; it
>   causes the regular expression engine to match as few occurrences as
>   possible.

In other words, `?` is greedy, and `??` is lazy. Both match zero or one time, but they will have an effect on how the matching is performed.

With regards to backtracking, [MSDN mentions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx#backtracking_with_optional_quantifiers_or_alternation_constructs):

> the regular expression engine tries to fully match optional or
>   alternative subexpressions. When it advances to the next language
>   element in the subexpression and the match is unsuccessful, the
>   regular expression engine can abandon a portion of its successful
>   match and return to an earlier saved state in the interest of matching
>   the regular expression as a whole with the input string. This process
>   of returning to a previous saved state to find a match is known as
>   backtracking.

Another useful resource to learn more about backtracking can be found here: [Possessive Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

To answer your question directly, we can compare both approaches.

### Greedy approach

**Original input:** `REFmisc03-123456789012-213`

Usage of `(REF)?` will match your text with 4 groups (excluding the first group with the entire match) and all groups will be successfully matched:

1. REF
2. misc03
3. 123456789012
4. 213

This matches your first possible match scenario (loosely defined):

> (REF)(misc03)-(123456789012)-(213)

As long as the `"misc..."` portion is 1-10 characters long, the match will be the same, with all 1-10 characters appearing in the second group. The `REF` portion will always be matched in the first group.

**New input:** `REF-123456789012-213`

The `"misc..."` portion is absent. Since `(REF)?` is optional, and `(.{1,10})` isn't, the regex engine will use the `"REF"` input to satisfy the latter (required) portion of the pattern and disregard the former (optional) portion. This will yield the following group values:

1. `""` (empty string, `Success` property = `false`)
2. REF
3. 123456789012
4. 213

### Lazy approach

**Original input:** `REFmisc03-123456789012-213`

By using `(REF)??`, and keeping the rest of your pattern the same, the quantifier becomes lazy and this returns 4 groups with these values:

1. `""` (empty string, `Success` property = `false`)
2. REFmisc03
3. 123456789012
4. 213

This matches your second possible match scenario:

> ()(REFmisc03)-(123456789012)-(213)

Since the first group is optional with a lazy quantifier, the regex engine is able to disregard it. Since `"REFmisc03"` is 9 characters long, the engine proceeds to lump `"REF"` in with `"misc03"` because they fit into the `(.{1,10})` group.

**New input:** `REF-123456789012-213`

This behaves similarly to the greedy pattern and the same reasoning applies.

**Another new input:** `REFmisc0345-123456789012-213`

In this example the `"misc0345"` portion is 8 characters long. Although the pattern uses a lazy quantifier it can't fit `"REFmisc0345"` into the second group because it exceeds the 10 character limit. The regex engine will backtrack and match `"REF"` in the first group, and `"misc0345"` in the second group:

1. REF
2. misc0345
3. 123456789012
4. 213